# Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert when i use UniswapV2router functions

Tags: solidity, truffle, uniswap, smart-contract-wallets

I'm using my owned cloned UniswapV2 smart contracts(core+periphery) and deployed them using ganache network, so when i start testing functions, i started with **createPair()** function located in UniswapV2Factory and it's working fine. But when i start using uniswapV2router functions like **addliquidity()** or **swapexactTokensForTokens()** it dosent't working, and throw error message :

```
Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
```

This is my deploy file where i used addLiquidity() function located in testliquidity contract:

```
const { sendEther, pow } = require("./util");
const IERC20 = artifacts.require("IERC20");
const TestLiquidity = artifacts.require("TestLiquidity");
const { ethers } = require("ethers");
const TOKEN_A = "0xFDAc1a07bB190930c45113BA0119b4F9c964aAb9";
const TOKEN_B = "0x21A347769867E169AF7444fe85F4E4bdE4A9c97e";
const ROUTER = "0xeEea9fc1B8c453105258F09BCa4d06086a909c91";
const TOKEN_A_AMOUNT = pow(10, 18);
const TOKEN_B_AMOUNT = pow(10, 18);
 
module.exports = async function (deployer, networks, accounts) {

  const tokenA = await IERC20.at(TOKEN_A);
  const tokenB = await IERC20.at(TOKEN_B);

  await deployer.deploy(TestLiquidity)
  const testliquidity = await TestLiquidity.deployed()

  await tokenA.approve(testliquidity.address, TOKEN_A_AMOUNT);
  await tokenB.approve(testliquidity.address, TOKEN_B_AMOUNT);

  let tx = await testliquidity.addLiquidity(
    tokenA.address,
    tokenB.address,
    TOKEN_A_AMOUNT,
    TOKEN_B_AMOUNT
  );
};
```

and this is the testliquidity contract where i called the addliquidity() function:

```
contract TestLiquidity {

  address private constant ROUTER = 0xeEea9fc1B8c453105258F09BCa4d06086a909c91;
  event Log(string message, uint val);

  function addLiquidity(
    address _tokenA,
    address _tokenB,
    uint _amountA,
    uint _amountB
  ) external {
    IERC20(_tokenA).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amountA);
    IERC20(_tokenB).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amountB);
    IERC20(_tokenA).approve(ROUTER, _amountA);
    IERC20(_tokenB).approve(ROUTER, _amountB);
    

    (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity) =
      IUniswapV2Router02(ROUTER).addLiquidity(
        _tokenA,
        _tokenB,
        _amountA,
        _amountB,
        1,
        1,
        address(this),
        block.timestamp
      );

    emit Log("amountA", amountA);
    emit Log("amountB", amountB);
    emit Log("liquidity", liquidity);
  }


}
```

and here is my ERC20 tokens contracts tokenA and tokenB which i created to add them in my liquidity pair:

```
contract tokenA is ERC20 {
  constructor() ERC20('USDC Coin', 'USDC') {
    uint256 n = 1000;
    _mint(msg.sender, n * 10**uint(decimals()));

  }

contract tokenB is ERC20 {
  constructor() ERC20('WBTC Coin', 'WBTC') {
      uint256 n = 1000;
      _mint(msg.sender, n * 10**uint(decimals()));
  }
}
}
```

I can't undestant from where the problem exactly, i'm sure the uniswapV2 contracts are correct and well deployed.

Comment: which network? How are you getting the contract addresses?

Comment: development newtork port 8545 using truffle ganache

Comment: Why are the contract addresses fixed? Should they not change on every deployment?

Comment: Im deploying them seperatly so each time i deploy them i get the contract addresses and call them, starting with core uniswapv2 contracts where i deployed factory and pair contracts then periphery contracts where i deployed weth and uniswapV2router using factory address that i've elrady deployed it, then i used that uniswapv2router contract address in testliquidity contract.

Comment: i said maybe from the tokenAamout and tokenBamount when i use the pow function, when i console log them i get:
<BN: 3782dace9d9>
<BN: 3782dace9d9>

Comment: Try deploying uniswap router inside the test and pass address of router to TestLiquidity

Comment: Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to test contracts using test file provided by truffle and got a similar error.
here is my test file:

```
const BN = require("bn.js");
const { sendEther, pow } = require("./util");
const TestLiquidity = artifacts.require("TestLiquidity");
const USDC = artifacts.require("USDC");
const WBTC = artifacts.require("WBTC");

contract("TestUniswapLiquidity", (accounts) => {
  const CALLER = accounts[0];
  const TOKEN_A_AMOUNT = pow(10, 18);
  const TOKEN_B_AMOUNT = pow(10, 18);
  let tokenA;
  let tokenB;

  beforeEach(async () => {

    tokenA =await USDC.new(); 
    tokenB = await WBTC.new(); 
    contract = await TestLiquidity.new(); 
    
    await tokenA.approve(contract.address, TOKEN_A_AMOUNT, { from: CALLER });
    await tokenB.approve(contract.address, TOKEN_B_AMOUNT, { from: CALLER });

    
  });

  it("add liquidity", async () => {
    let tx = await contract.addLiquidity(
      tokenA.address,
      tokenB.address,
      TOKEN_A_AMOUNT,
      TOKEN_B_AMOUNT,
      {
        from: CALLER,
      }
    );
    console.log("=== add liquidity ===");
    for (const log of tx.logs) {
      console.log(`${log.args.message} ${log.args.val}`);
    }   
  });
});
```

and got this error:

```
Contract: TestUniswapLiquidity
    1) add liquidity

    Events emitted during test:
    ---------------------------

    Ambiguous event, possible interpretations:
    * ERC20.Transfer(
        from: <indexed> 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (type: address),
        to: <indexed> 0x138A24E2dCD31c145616386b15f336A70F661E8d (type: address),
        value: 1000000000000000000000 (type: uint256)
      )
    * ERC20.Transfer(
        from: <indexed> 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (type: address),
        to: <indexed> 0x138A24E2dCD31c145616386b15f336A70F661E8d (type: address),
        value: 1000000000000000000000 (type: uint256)
      )

    Ambiguous event, possible interpretations:
    * ERC20.Transfer(
        from: <indexed> 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (type: address),
        to: <indexed> 0x138A24E2dCD31c145616386b15f336A70F661E8d (type: address),
        value: 1000000000000000000000 (type: uint256)
      )
    * ERC20.Transfer(
        from: <indexed> 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (type: address),
        to: <indexed> 0x138A24E2dCD31c145616386b15f336A70F661E8d (type: address),
        value: 1000000000000000000000 (type: uint256)
      )

    Ambiguous event, possible interpretations:
    * ERC20.Approval(
        owner: <indexed> 0x138A24E2dCD31c145616386b15f336A70F661E8d (type: address),
        spender: <indexed> 0xc02F361d24ef98E74A579EaA8c5277aCFc83435e (type: address),
        value: 1000000000000000000 (type: uint256)
      )
    * ERC20.Approval(
        owner: <indexed> 0x138A24E2dCD31c145616386b15f336A70F661E8d (type: address),
        spender: <indexed> 0xc02F361d24ef98E74A579EaA8c5277aCFc83435e (type: address),
        value: 1000000000000000000 (type: uint256)
      )

    Ambiguous event, possible interpretations:
    * ERC20.Approval(
        owner: <indexed> 0x138A24E2dCD31c145616386b15f336A70F661E8d (type: address),
        spender: <indexed> 0xc02F361d24ef98E74A579EaA8c5277aCFc83435e (type: address),
        value: 1000000000000000000 (type: uint256)
      )
    * ERC20.Approval(
        owner: <indexed> 0x138A24E2dCD31c145616386b15f336A70F661E8d (type: address),
        spender: <indexed> 0xc02F361d24ef98E74A579EaA8c5277aCFc83435e (type: address),
        value: 1000000000000000000 (type: uint256)
      )


    ---------------------------


  0 passing (8s)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: TestUniswapLiquidity
       add liquidity:
     Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\test_liquidity.js:38:29)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```